# Dictionary keys don't contain a key that's already contained in keys

Tags: c#, dictionary, key, gethashcode, equals-operator

Why is the following 'exist' boolean variable getting a value of false???

```
foreach (Cell existCell in this.decoratorByCell.Keys)
{   
            //this call yield the same hashcode for both cells. still exist==false
            bool exist =
                this.decoratorByCell.ContainsKey(existCell);
}
```

I've overridden GetHashCode() & Equals() Methods as follows:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
            string nodePath = GetNodePath();

            return nodePath.GetHashCode() + m_ownerColumn.GetHashCode();
}

public bool Equals(Cell other)
{
bool nodesEqual = (other.OwnerNode == null && this.OwnerNode == null) || (other.GetNodePath() == this.GetNodePath());
bool columnsEqual = (other.OwnerColumn == null && this.OwnerColumn == null) || (other.OwnerColumn == this.OwnerColumn);
bool treesEqual = (this.m_ownerTree == other.m_ownerTree);

return (nodesEqual && columnsEqual && treesEqual);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementations do very different things. They should be mirroring each other.

You have no mention in `GetHashCode` to the `m_ownerTree` that you are using in your `Equals` implementation.

Also, adding up hashcodes is not the bast way of computing a hash. You may want to xor them (`^`) up.

Answer (score 1):

A hash algorithm *must* have the following property:

- if two things are equal then they have the same hash

A hash algorithm *should* have the following properties:

- changing a mutable object does not change its hash code
- fast
- never throw an exception
- small differences between objects should cause large (ideally 50% of the bits) differences in hash code

Does your hash algorithm have the first, necessary property? It doesn't look to me like it does.

Comment: The .NET Framework documentation actually has a better description of what it must do and also clarifies your #1 should-do case: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx